# Error with the command onkey()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to create a shooter-like game in Python turtle (it's basically a copy of the game `Boom dots`). But I'm having a lot of issues, because I'm kind of new to programming. This time the command onkey() doesn't work. I tried everything but nothing seems to be of help.
I don't get any traceback errors. It's just that defined command doesn't work when I press the button which is assigned to the command.

Part of code in which I suspect the problem is:

```
def cannon_left():
  cannon_x = cannon_x - 10
  cannon.goto(cannon_x, 0)

def cannon_right():
  cannon_x = cannon_x + 10
  cannon.goto(cannon_x, 0)

def reset1():
  live_score = 0
```

The whole code:

```
import random
import turtle

#images
image_coconut = "Coconut.png"
image_banana = "Banana.png"
image_pineapple = "Pineapple.png"
image_cannon = "Cannon.png"

#definitions
live_score = 0
screen = turtle.Screen()
wn = turtle.Screen()
cannon = turtle.Turtle()
enemy = turtle.Turtle()
score = turtle.Turtle()
background = turtle.Turtle()
reset = turtle.Turtle()
bullet = turtle.Turtle()
enemy_x = enemy.xcor()
enemy_y = enemy.ycor()
cannon_x = 0
move_speed = 2
enemy1 = 0

def cannon_shooting(x, y):
  bullet.showturtle()
  bullet.forward(280)
  if bullet.ycor() == enemy_y - 10:
    if not bullet.xcor() == enemy_x - 10:
      if live_score == 0:
        live_score = 0
      else:
        live_score = live_score + 1
    if bullet.xcor() == enemy_x - 10:
      live_score = live_score + 1
      enemy1 = random.randint(1, 3)
  bullet.hideturtle()


#image adding
screen.addshape(image_coconut)
screen.addshape(image_banana)
screen.addshape(image_pineapple)
screen.addshape(image_cannon)

def cannon_left():
  cannon_x = cannon_x - 10
  cannon.goto(cannon_x, 0)

def cannon_right():
  cannon_x = cannon_x + 10
  cannon.goto(cannon_x, 0)

def reset1():
  live_score = 0

#setup
bullet.hideturtle()
bullet.speed(50)
bullet.penup()
bullet.shape('circle')
bullet.goto(0, -140)
bullet.left(90)

enemy.speed(0)
enemy.penup()
enemy.hideturtle()
enemy.goto(0, 140)
screen.addshape(image_coconut)
enemy.shape(image_coconut)
enemy.showturtle()

cannon.speed(0)
cannon.penup()
cannon.hideturtle()
cannon.goto(0, -140)
screen.addshape(image_cannon)
cannon.shape(image_cannon)
cannon.showturtle()
cannon.left(90)

score.speed(0)
score.penup()
score.hideturtle()
score.goto(90, -190)
score.color('white')
score.write("Your score: %s" % live_score, font=(None, 11, "bold"))

reset.speed(0)
reset.penup()
reset.hideturtle()
reset.goto(-185, -190)
reset.color('white')
reset.write("Reset (R)", font=(None, 11, "bold"))

#movement
while True:
  enemy.forward(move_speed)
  if enemy.xcor() == 140:
    enemy.left(180)
    enemy.forward(move_speed)
  if enemy.xcor() == -140:
    enemy.right(180)
    enemy.forward(move_speed)
    if enemy1 == 1:
      screen.addshape(image_banana)
      enemy.shape(image_banana)
    if enemy1 == 2:
      screen.addshape(image_pineapple)
      enemy.shape(image_pineapple)
    if enemy1 == 3:
      enemy.shape(image_coconut)

#key presses
wn.onkey(cannon_right, "D")
wn.onkey(cannon_left, "A")
wn.onkey(cannon_right, "Right")
wn.onkey(cannon_left, "Left")
wn.onkey(cannon_shooting, "SPACE")
wn.onkey(reset1, "R")

#others
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

**Note:** I'm creating the game in `Trinket.io`. Click [here](https://trinket.io/python/ed2c612824) to go to the `Trinket.io` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is an imperative programming language. This means that *order matters*. What appears to be the main logic of your game is declared before the `onkey` initialization part as an infinite loop:

```
#movement
while True:
  enemy.forward(move_speed)
  ...
```

As this loop runs forever, it means that will start executing and the code will never reach the part where you set up the key mapping.

You need the code that is in the loop put this code in a function, and decide when exactly it needs to be called by Turtle. You should not put the `while True` as part of the function, as there  already exists a main loop managed by Turtle.

Comment: Thanks. That helps. Now I can move the cannon. But the enemy (aka Coconut) stops moving. How may I fix this?